In a compact Riemannian manifold can we get a sufficiently big geodesic ball such it coincides with the manifold itself?
Let $(M, g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $\xi\in M.$ Set $B_r(\xi)=\{x\in M; d_g(x, \xi)<r\},$ where $d_g$ is the geodesic distance. Is there a radius $r>0,$ such that $B_r(\xi)=M$?

If not, then $B_r(\xi)$ is a covering of $M$ with no finite sub cover, contradicting compactness.

look up "Cut Locus"

But if not, ${B_r(\xi)}$ wouldn't be a covering, isn't it?

${B_r(\xi) \mid r>0}$ is always a covering, no matter what metric space $M$ you are in. Take an arbitrary $x \in M$ and let $r = 1 + d_g(x,\xi)$; it follows that $x \in B_r(\xi)$.

I should add, though, that you might want to assume connectedness. Without that, $d_g$ is not a metric because $d_g(x,y)$ is undefined if $x$, $y$ are in different connected components.

Proof try: Since $M$ is compact, the $\sup_{(x, y)\in M\times M}d_g(x, y)$ is finite. Then, $r=\sup_{(x, y)\in M\times M}d_g(x, y)$ satisfies the equality of sets $B_r(\xi)=M.$

Almost. Test this on a circle.

Correct! You have to pick $r$ any bigger. Thanks!
